# Animate element moving between lists

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, angularjs-directive, angularjs-animation

Using AngularJS, I would like to animate an element being added to one list from another, as in a clone of the element should appear to move in the page from the menu of items, and be added to the target list.

```
<ul class="list">
  <li ng-click="choose(item)" ng-repeat="item in originItems">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="item in targetItems track by $index">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Where the function that adds the items does a simple push

```
$scope.choose = function(item) {
  $scope.targetItems.push(item);
}
```

You can [see this in action (with no animation) at this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JSvLHRqmbbRlEhHJqPBP?p=preview)

I've considered custom directives and events, but not really got anywhere. What's a good structure of directives and/or events to allow this movement animation be achieved, keeping this a separate from the business of adding to a list as possible?

Note: my exact situation in terms of business logic and animation is a bit different, but I'm hoping the solution to this is flexible enough to allow some changes/additions to what happens in the menu, during the "move" animation, and what happens in the target list.

Answer (score 3):

#### Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/XYnf7U?p=preview

1. I removed list style to ensure proper position of list item while moving. If you have to enable list style, you have to consider that.
2. The demo works by: when user add an item, it get the position of original and final items, and apply a jquery animation to the cloned list item between those two positions.
3. Use `$event.target` to identify original item.

Comment: I considered things much more complicated than just using a dynamic .animate function, so thanks! However, is there a way to do this without depending on an ID though? Some way for the target item to "know" where it came from?

Comment: @MichalCharemza you don't have to use ID of item. You are using `$scope.targetItems.push(item);` to push the same item into another array, so you can use `===` to check.

Comment: In your example you're using the ID '#original-list'. Is there a way to make this a bit more general, to not depend on an ID. Say if you have multiple lists on a page?

Comment: @MichalCharemza sorry I misunderstood you. I just updated the demo and removed `extractOriginalItem` function. I used `$event.target` to identify original item element.

Comment: Ah... that is better in that regard. But then the controller has to access the $event. I'm hoping for more of a separation between the business logic of adding to an array, and the "sugar" of the animation, as my actual case will be more complicated.

Comment: @MichalCharemza this is the easiest approach I can think of. I have to access the event in controller because animate enter method only knows a new item is added, but it doesn't know how it was added, thus no way to find out which item is the original dom element. However, after calculate the position and animation, you can delete the attached $event property on item object.